# Insert a row for each user in database (sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

**What I want to do:**
On the website I'm creating you can write messages which will end up in the `message` table with an ID and the entered title, text and so on. What I want to do is when this message is created I want to create an SQL call that gives **all** users in the relational database a row in the `user_messages` table with a connection to the newly created message and the `user_messages.read` set to 0.

#### Table structure

[image: Database structure]

#### user_messages table

[image: user_messages table]

**My question:**
What is the easiest way to insert a row (like image 2) in `user_messages` for every single user with an ID when the new message is created?

---

I've tried to do something like this but it didn't work

```
INSERT INTO `user_messages` (
    `user_id`
    ,`message_id`
    ,`read`
    )
VALUES (
    ['*']
    ,[<new-message-id>]
    ,['0']
    )
```

Comment: Why to insert even if it is not read ? Maybe is better if it is not read to not insert, so you will know, each time someones read a message you have one row inserted with read flag. So if you have a row is read, if not then is not read.

Comment: Strange way to do this. (For example consider the case when a new user is created, what to do with all existing messages?)

Comment: @Simion That is actually a good point I didn't think of that. :D Although I would still like to know how to do something like this if I would ever need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
INSERT INTO `user_messages`(`user_id`, `message_id`, `read`) 
SELECT `user_id`, [<new-message-id>], ['0'] FROM `users`
```

Comment: When testing your solution I get the following error:  
`Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'` ( I of course swapped "<new-message-id>" with an actual existing message ID, in this case, '1')
Can you elaborate on how your code works in more detail

Comment: It takes all `user_id`'s from table users, than add for each of them `massage-id` and 0 for `read` and then insert it into table `user_massages`. Are you sure there is no row in `user_messages` that will be duplicated?

Comment: I don't know actually. I made sure to empty all rows in `user_messages` to make sure that no user gets a connection to the same message twice. Still getting the same error though. I can't find where there is a clash

Comment: Dunno. Is it possible that you have duplicate id's in `users` table? Is your PRIMARY on `user_messages` properly defined? (both on `massage-id` and `user_id`)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert into both table in same go

```
INSERT INTO user_messages t1, messages t1 (t1.E1, t1.E2, t2.E1, t2.E2)
```